# При запуске возникает ошибка сегментации памяти

Tags: c++, дерево

При запуске возникает ошибка сегментации памяти (стек памяти сброшен на диск). Понимаю что происходит из-за утечки памяти ,но вчитываясь в код не могу найти причину этой ошибки , буду рад любой помощи , сам новичок не судите строго .В этом проекте пытался реализовать бинарное дерево для сортировки чисел в порядке возраст. принимающее значения через аргумент командной строки .

```
#include "stdlib.h"

struct Node{
    int Data;
    Node *left = nullptr;
    Node *right = nullptr;
};
class SearchTree {

private:
    Node *head = nullptr;

    static void Desrtroi_elem(Node *node) {
        if (node) {
            Desrtroi_elem(node->left);
            Desrtroi_elem(node->right);
            delete node;
        }
    }

public:
    SearchTree() {
        head = new Node ;
    }

    ~SearchTree() {
        Desrtroi_elem(head);
    }

    void Print(Node *node, int u) {
        if (node = nullptr) {
            return;
        } else {
            Print(node->left, ++u);
            for (int i = 0; i < u; ++i) {
                std::cout << " | " << node->Data << std::endl;
                u--;

            }
        }
        Print(node->right, ++u);

    }

//    int Min(){
//
//
//    }
    void Insert(int a, Node **node) {
        if (*node) {
            (*node) = new Node;
            (*node)->Data = a;
            (*node)->left = (*node)->right = nullptr;
            return;
        }
        if (a > (*node)->Data) {
            Insert(a, &(*node)->right);
        } else {
            Insert(a, &(*node)->left);
        }
    }
//    int Max(){
//
//    }
};
int main(int argc , char **argv ) {
    int i;
    SearchTree first ;

    for (i = 0 ; i <= argc ;i++){
        std::cout<< argv[i]<<std::endl;

    }
    int result = 1;
    for (i = 0 ; i <= argc ;i++){
        int x = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10);
        result = x;
    }
    Node *root = NULL;
    first.Insert(result,&root);
    first.Print(root, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (*node) { (*node) = new Node;` - ничего в условии вы не забыли?

Comment: дописал == nullptr , ошибка осталась .

Comment: Забавная конструкция `if (node = nullptr) {`, нет? Выхода за пределы массива не боитесь? `for (i = 0 ; i <= argc ;i++){` — `strtol(NULL` чему равен? Вы вообще свой собственный код сколько раз читали? Предупреждения компилятора?

Comment: [Как отлаживать маленькие программы](https://habr.com/ru/post/339038/)

Comment: Интересно получается , задаешь вопрос , где сам не сможешь найти ответ , такие как вы просто скидывают на то что я не опытный (хотя я это указал и вопроса бы не было бесли бы был больше опыт ) Прежде чем писать ерунду и тратить свое время подумайте пожалуйста , я не прошу высказывать свое мнене о моей не опытности , а подсказки и помощи для дальнейщей работы. Зачем писать не опытному человеку ,  о его скилле это абсурд . Если ничем не можете помочь , не выписывайте фигни .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще вам просто следует внимательнее относится к памяти, вам указали на явные ошибки в комментариях, исправьте их для начала. А в практике обычно используют специальную опцию компилятора - санитайзер - она проверяет и говорит вам о том где и какие утечки. Установите компиллятор gcc или g++("или" потому, что библиотека stdlib.h это библиотека языка си , а классы это с++. В с++ используйте cstdlib). После установки компиллируйте так :

```
g++ programm.cpp -o nameOfProgram -fsanitize=address
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное , хоть один адекватный ответ .